# How can I specify a return type for a $http call with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here's my function so far. I already added an interface for the two input parameters but because of the way that this is coded I really don't know how to deal with the return parameters:

```
function httpGetQuestion(q: ITestQuestion, action: string) {
    return $http({
        url: '/api/Question/GetByUId/' + q.questionUId + '/' + action,
        method: "GET"
    })
}
```

also:

```
httpGetQuestion(q, 'fetch')
    .success(function (data) {
```

Here is the data that gets returned from the $http call:

```
    public class Q
    {
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the typing for your return value as ng.IHttpPromise:- Using and interface for your service and adding the interface as typing on your dependency, and adding comments (JSDoc) on your interface methods will give you nice intellisense as well providing the description and other information about the method.

Something like this:-

```
export interface IMyService{
        /**
         * Returns promise which will resolve to .....
         * @returns {ng.IHttpPromise<Q>}
         */
        httpGetQuestion(q: ITestQuestion, action: string) : ng.IHttpPromise<Q>;
}


class MyService implements IMyService{

 constructor(...
        private $http: ng.IHttpService,
        ...) {

    }

  .....    

   httpGetQuestion(q: ITestQuestion, action: string) {
     return this.$http({
        url: '/api/Question/GetByUId/' + q.questionUId + '/' + action,
        method: "GET"
     });
   }

 ....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inline:

```
function httpGetQuestion(q: ITestQuestion, action: string) : ng.IHttpPromise<Q> {
```